# I am trying pass HTML code returned from a function as a prop to another component. But it dosen't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the function which return HTML code in a variable

```
let rating = (stars) => {
    // console.log(stars)
    const string = <i className="fas fa-star"></i>
    let star = '';
    // console.log(string)
    for (let i = 0;  i <= stars; i++) {
        star += string
        console.log(star)  
    }
    // console.log(star.toString())
    return (
      star
    )
}
```

I am calling this function from here, passing in the number of stars
[Here's a screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B03A6.png)

```
        <Pet id={'cat'} price={'$30.00'} rating={rating(4)} quantity={cat} handleIncrement={onIncrement} handleDecrement={onDecrement} />
        <Pet id={'dog'} price={'$15.00'} rating={rating(1)} quantity={dog} handleIncrement={onIncrement} handleDecrement={onDecrement} />
        <Pet id={'fish'} price={'$25.00'} rating={rating(3)} quantity={fish} handleIncrement={onIncrement} handleDecrement={onDecrement} />
        <Pet id={'dove'} price={'$20.00'} rating={rating(5)} quantity={dove} handleIncrement={onIncrement} handleDecrement={onDecrement} />
        <Pet id={'frog'} price={'$17.00'} rating={rating(2)} quantity={frog} handleIncrement={onIncrement} handleDecrement={onDecrement} />
```

Comment: the <i> should be enclosed with single quotes to be considered a string `const string ='<i className="fas fa-star"></i>'`

Comment: Also instead of passing the HTML, why don't you just pass the number of stars and render them inside the Pet component?

Comment: Actually, the **string** variable is not a string type. It is an object. That's why you are seeing the 'object' strings in the result. Why don't you pass only the rating number to the  **Pet** component and render **star**s inside it?